# Shiny fileInput parameter "accept" issue

Tags: r, shiny

I want restrict uploading file in fileInput in Shiny but if I use parameter accept like

```
fileInput("file_input","Choose your file",accept =".csv")
```

so I can upload all type file like txt.

Is it any choice how to accept uploading only csv? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write comma seperated values inside a txt file, that's why it gives you a possibility to upload txt probably.

But you can do something like this on the server where you read the file, to cut it's name into pieces by `.` symbol, and check if the last piece (which is it's extension) is the extension you need:

```
name1 <- strsplit(input$file_input$name, split = ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]

      if (name1[length(name1)] == "csv") {
        # ... do something
      } else {
        # throw an error
      }
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/951#issuecomment-141300800